# wp-cli and job.execute

Tags: scheduled-job

I'm trying to follow the WP set up instructions for scheduled jobs https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/ using wp-cli

I can't figure out if I have things working correctly or not!

What response am I expecting when I run the wp-cli job.execute command?

I get:

Array
(
    [is_error] => 0
    [version] => 3
    [count] => 1
    [values] => 1
)

In the civicrm wp admin panel the system status shows last cron job run at approx the time when I ran the wp-cli command , so I guesss this means things are working ok?

But the logs in admin/system setting/scheduled jobs don't show any matching logs for the enabled jobs ?

Comment: update - figured it out now!  the response , I think, is fine.  logs only generated if the specific job runs which is determined by the Run Frequency setting

Comment: If you figure out the answer to your own question (well done!) the preferred format in SE is to write that as an answer rather than an update or comment to the question.  That helps other people find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out now! the response , I think, is fine. logs only generated if the specific job runs which is determined by the Run Frequency settings